# configuration for xamarin and visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, xamarin

i have a MAC airbook core2deo processor with 2GB RAM .I want to know can i install window 8 or window 10 and Visual Studio2015.Is this configuration is sufficient or i will have to update latest mac machine for XAMARIN.

Answer (score 0):

for xamarin development you can use xamarin studio for mac by which you don't need any dependency for windows and visual studio untill you have any specific need.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/mac/

Answer (score 0):

My advice, install Xamarin Studio and XCode on your Mac, buy a good PC, have Visual Studio on PC. You'll be able to build apps for all 3 paltform, because you can't build a iOS app on PC, and you can't build an Windows app on Mac. But you can build an iOS app using VS if you are connected to a Mac that have Xamarin Studio and XCode installed.